# Manifest version 2 for news reader

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to install the [news reader](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#news-reader) from the chrome example extentions

but it isn't working without even making a change. so because it wants manifest v2 I added the `manifest_version: 2` to the manifest and that gave me the following:

```
{
  "name": "__MSG_name__",
  "version": "1.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "__MSG_description__",
  "icons": { "128": "news_icon.png" },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "__MSG_default_title__",
    "default_icon": "news_action.png",
    "default_popup": "feed.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://news.google.com/*",
    "http://news.google.es/*"
  ],
  "default_locale": "en"
}
```

But how would I update it to fix the following errors:

```
feed.html:75 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

feed.html:103 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

feed.html:308 Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

Comment: Lopk at the manifest documentation. There are permissions for that.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [handy guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#restrictions) at the Content Security Policy documentation. It also mentions that it can't be solved by modifying CSP itself in case of inline scripts.

Specifically, read the section on [inline scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution).

In short, the following changes are needed in your case (based on the errors):

- If there are any `<script> /* some code */ </script>` blocks, they need to be moved in a separate file and loaded with `<script src="file.js"></script>`
- If there are any inline handlers like `<div onclick="clickHandler()">` or `<body onload="load()">`, they need to be converted to `addEventListener` format and performed from included JS code. See the documentation for examples.

Don't hesitate to raise a bug at https://crbug.com to indicate that the sample is out of date.